# C# DateTimeOffset comparision with LocalDate

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I'm consuming a Microsoft API which returns `DateTimeOffset`. The property has following documentation- **This value is calculated based on current UTC time measured locally.**

I want to compare this time with local server where my application is hosted. (So the DateTimeOffset is returned by Microsoft API and the place where I want to compare is on my server. These 2 can have different time zones).

When inspecting `DateTimeOffset`, Date & UTC property has same Date & Time and the `Kind` property is unspecified.

I'm currently using `DateTimeOffset < DateTime.UtcNow` for checking condition. Am I doing right?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dateTimeOffset.LocalDateTime  < dateTime`.

`.LocalDateTime` method will convert the `DateTimeOffset` into your local time zone (with `DateTimeKind.Local`), so you can safely compare with your local `DateTime`.

Comment: This seems reasonably true and I'll give it try, check in staging and see everythig is as expected to mark this answer! Shouldn't that condition be `DateTimeOffset.ToLocalTime().DateTime < DateTime.Now` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the offset time difference in the minutes using the below code

```
// Get the GMT time difference offset (This is your local time offset difference)
var timeOffsetinMiniut = DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.TotalMinutes;
```

Now you can use add this offset in you local time to make it a UTC time.

```
var myNewDateTime = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeOffsetinMiniut)
```

Now you can compare both time utc time and your new server time.

```
myNewDateTime  < DateTime.UtcNow
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt if this will work since you haven't used `DateTimeOffset` anywhere in above explanation. here in above context, `DateTimeOffset` is a variable having value that is returned from Microsoft API.